# Making a loading screen when player collides (doesnt work)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player");
    {
      StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously(1));
    }
  }

    IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously (int sceneIndex)
    {
       AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);

       while (!operation.isDone)
       {
          yield return null;
       }
    }
}
```

I tried changing some things but it's not working anyways if someone can help me. is supposed to work when collides with that object but IDK why nothing happens

Comment: Can you please make sure that gameobject which this script attached to and the player has colliders?

Comment: is the collision working? have you tried to debug.log() the player inside the OnCollisionEnter?

Comment: Well is supposed that when u collide with this cube that is triggered the player complete the level.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/353359492672520193/823747843017801798/unknown.png
Sorry for the link but there u can see the specifications too and if u want something more about the properties tell me

Comment: And yep the collision is supposed to be working, cause i created a code that makes u destroy when u collide with the tag "Enemy", IDK what could be not working

Comment: Have you tried just putting "SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex)" in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a bool flag for it

```
bool loadScene = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player");
    {
      if(!loadScene){
      StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously(1));
      loadScene = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well I did this https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/353359492672520193/823768630209675294/unknown.png?width=873&height=473
IDK if u have some suggestion about how this could work.

Comment: Have you tried it? OnCollisionEnter will trigger every frame so make it a bool flag to trigger it only once.

Comment: the problem is that IDK how to know that, if I'm not using Unity Remote 5